# Finding $f$ from $f$'s derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which can derives with $f(0)=0$ and: $$2xf(x)=(x^2+1)f(x)-(x^2+1)f'(x)+1$$
I want to find the $f$, so I am thinking of using the theorem that: $$F'(x)=G'(x)\iff F(x)=G(x)+c$$
But I don't know to apply this exactly in my case. Any ideas?

Comment: This is is called "ordinary differential equation". There's a whole field dedicated to solving problem like this.

Comment: I don't have time to solve it right now, but I think it would help to rearrange the equation like this: $f'(x)+u(x)*f(x)=v(x)$, and then multiply both sides by $\exp(\int u)$, and you can use now the product rule: $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$.

Comment: @xyzzyz what is difference between ode and pde

Comment: $x\mapsto \frac{e^x-1}{x^2+1}$

Comment: @KingTut A pde has partial derivatives, and the functions have several variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
2xf(x)&=(x^2+1)f(x)-(x^2+1)f'(x)+1 \\
2xf(x)+(x^2+1)f'(x)&=(x^2+1)f(x)+1 \\
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
\int 2xf(x)+(x^2+1)f'(x)dx=(x^2+1)f(x)
\end{align}
by product rule.

Comment: How to proceed now

Answer (score 1):

On rearrangement, you will get a [linear differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation). Writing $f(x)$ as $y$.

$$(x^2+1)y'-(x-1)^2y=1$$

Using integration factor $\exp\left(\int \tfrac{-(x-1)^2}{x^2+1}dx\right) = e^{-x}(x^2+1)$, the solution is given as:

$$y(e^{-x})(x^2+1)=\int e^{-x} dx=-e^{-x}+c$$